# jhipster - log set to error but non error logs show

Tags: jhipster

I have set the log level to Error on all packages of my webapp (in admin part of the webapp) but I am still getting non error logs in stdout file.
Is it normal?
Additionnal question : how can I add the date and time in the error logs? Is it configurable in my jhipster project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about logging in JHipster, it just uses spring-boot logging on top of logback, just read [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html) and [logback manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/index.html).

There are 2 files to look at:

- `src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml` for app execution
- `src/test/resources/logback-test.xml` for tests execution